# генератор символов

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

Как и можно ли вообще генерировать с помощью стандартной библиотеки "random":

- случайную строку (с заданным диапазоном символов, например 10 символов или 5)
- случайную строку со случайными цифрами ("1fds89OOPdb"),
- числа типа float, double

Comment: @StateItPrimitive - Я так понял что стандартных методов для моих нужд в этой библиотеке нет и нужно все таки "изобретать велосипед".

Comment: По крайней мере, готовых решений сразу в голову не приходит, поэтому могу предложить только так, если еще кто знает, то возможно предложат варианты иных ответов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Общая последовательность действий уже описана. А для генерации случайных чисел (как Вы уже заметили) в C++ есть стандартная библиотека . Приведу лишь пример использования для наглядности (протестировать можно на [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>

int main ()
{
    std::string str;
    std::mt19937 gen ( time(NULL) );
    std::uniform_int_distribution <int> uid1 ( 5, 10 );
    int num = uid1 ( gen );
    int r;
    std::uniform_int_distribution <int> uid2 ( '0', 'z' );
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        do {r=uid2(gen);}while((r>'9' && r<'A') || (r>'Z' && r<'a'));
        str+=r;
    }
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Max_ZS Добавлю, что инициализировать через `time(NULL)` при наличии `<random>` даже странно :) - для этой цели теперь имеется `std::random_device`.

Comment: @Harry Боюсь, что именно с std::random_device это будет выглядеть более странно. Потому как он будет далеко не везде и не всегда работать. Реализация его зависит как от ОСи, так и от компилятора. Может как нормально работать, так и бросать исключения, а также выдавать ноль, что буде приводить к одной и той же последовательности.  Если код пишется для себя и конкретной машины, то можно проверить и если заработает, то использовать и успокоиться. В противном случае, не стОит его использовать.

Comment: @Max_ZS Ориентируюсь на "Discovering Modern C++" - не вижу оснований не верить советам книг серии C++ In-Depth :) Кстати, если тут http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device еще упоминается возможность детерминизма, то об исключениях нет ни слова.

Comment: @Harry чтение советов из книг должно подкрепляться практикой. Для минимального теста я привел конкретную [ссылку](http://cpp.sh/). Если Вы вставите туда свой пример, обернув его в try/catch, то увидите то самое исключение, о котором нет на  cppreference.com ни слова.

Comment: @Harry Предполагаю, что этот сайт не является догмой в описании STL. С таким же успехом могу привести Вам аналогичный (более старый сайт [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/random_device/?kw=random_device)), где Вы прочтете больше про random_device. А также могу дать и другие ссылки, где Вы сможете прочесть о разнообразном его поведении. И уже то, что  random_device проявляет разное поведение, побуждает меня отказываться от его применения, тем более советовать его использовать другим.

Comment: @Max_ZS По вашей ссылке http://cpp.sh/ только Hello-программа :) - уточните, pls, ссылку. Хотелось бы посмотреть. Если дело так плохо - напишу Готтшлигу...

Comment: @Harry Это не хеллоу-программа, а ссылка на онлайн-компилятор, где можете протестировать именно свой код. Как и на всех других онлайн-компиляторах, для примера вставлен код хеллоу-программы. Я предложил Вам (перечитайте мой комментарий), скопировать код с ссылки, предложенной Вами, обернуть его в try/catch и вставить его в компилятор (в мою ссылку). Извиняюсь, за возможно невнятное изложение (не по шагам) в предыдущих комментариях.

Comment: @Max_ZS Сейчас cpp.sh не грузится, я на ideone - или это принципиально на cpp.sh? Вот тут - http://ideone.com/pe5UcM - вы этого хотели или я опять что-то не так понял? Потому что никаких исключений пока нет. Если что-то не так понял - пожалуйста, дайте полный код, который приводит к генерации исключения...

Comment: @Harry У меня он всегда грузится (быстрее или медленнее, но грузится). И да. Принципиально на cpp.sh. Потому как изначально я написал, про разное поведение на разных системах и компиляторах. Вы же изначально сомневались в этом. Так это и есть пример того, что на ideone.com код работает, а на cpp.sh - нет. Или мы другой вопрос обсуждаем и я где-то потерял мысль обсуждения?

Comment: @Harry на счет наличия/отсутствия возможных исключений см. Стандарт 26.5.6/4 `Throws: A value of an implementation-defined type derived from exception if the random_device could not be initialized.` и т.д.

Comment: OK, Готтшлигу как errata к его книге написал, жду, что ответит (если ответит :))

Comment: Забавно, что сейчас на cpp.sh работает, вообще ничего не выводя... http://cpp.sh/8m2q7 Так что пошлет меня Готтшлиг далеко...

Comment: @Harry Не знаю, чего и кто там ответит, но я могу лишь предполагать (это сугубо мои домыслы, не имеющие под собой основы в виде Готтшлига) почему так происходит... Дело в том, что random_device - это, как бы так выразиться, "железная" генерация случайной последовательности. Т.е. задействовано в той или иной форме "железо"/оборудование (а уже как данные передаются - через файлы или "напрямую" - это уже другой вопрос).

Comment: @Harry И у меня есть предположение, что как минимум на серверах (VPS/VDS) именно связь железа с системой (а точнее даже не связь, а возможности доступа системы к железу) зависит от типа виртулизации. Так, например, виртуальная машина будет иметь больше возможностей даже для работы с ядром оси, чем виртуальный контейнер. Может быть более сведующие в этих вопросах люди быстрее даже разъяснят подобные вопросы, чем тот же Готтшлиг.

Answer (score 2):

Сразу в голову не приходит готового решения с использованием стандартных библиотечных функций непосредственно для таких целей, поэтому можно исхитриться:

1. Сначала генерируем число (средствами [C](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/), либо [C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), если есть такая возможность), которое будет отвечать за длину строки со случайными символами, затем для каждого символа генерировать его код (в определенных пределах, конечно же), котовый будет соответствовать символу из [таблицы символов ASCII](http://book.itep.ru/10/ascii.htm).
   Либо заводим массив всех необходимых символов (например, английский алфавит), а затем с помощью генератора случайных чисел генерировать индекс из этого массива и по нему выводить символ.
2. Для каждого символа строки сначала генерировать случайное число `0` или `1` (но так как чисел меньше чем других символов, то вероятность получить `0` должна отличаться от `1`, т.е. необходимо вероятностное пространство с неравномерным распределением) и по его значению принимать решение чем будет являться текущий символ, т.е. генерировать число или код символа (как генерировать последнее смотри п.1).
   Либо, опять же, можно завести готовый массив символов (включая цифры), как в п.1, а затем генерировать число, которое будет является индексом элемента из данного массива и обращаться к нему.
3. Сначала сгенерировать целое число, представляющее целую часть будущего числа с плавающей точкой, а затем второе целое число, которая затем будет являться дробной частью числа с плавающей точкой, а затем сконкатенировать их. Только необходимо предусмотреть тот факт, что в таком случае возможно превысить максимально доступное количество *значащих цифр числа* с плавающей точкой.

Для того, чтобы использовать вероятностное пространство с неравномерным распределением (в одном из пунктов я пояснил где это необходимо), то можно прибегнуть к новшествам стандарта `C++11` (если у вас такая возможности имеется, конечно), например, посредством `std::default_random_engine` и `std::bernoulli_distribution` (которые находятся в `#include <random>`).

Comment: спасибо за объяснения, я тогда как начинающий обойдусь пока что "time(0) + to_string + md5" - дешево и со вкусом...Может есть еще какие библиотеки для данных целей?

Comment: @Duracell Честно говоря, не знаю. Возможно, этот вопрос вскоре (в течение нескольких дней) привлечет внимания более осведомленных в этой области людей и, возможно, они смогут дать более подходящее решение (возможно, с помощью каких-нибудь библиотек).

Comment: @Duracell А вам последний предложенный вариант точно не подходит? (заранее завести массив из всех необходимых символов, а затем генерировать число, которое является индексом этого массива, и обращаться к элементу по этому индекусу).

Comment: да мне и твой способ подойдет и товарища "Max ZS", оба варианта проверил - все работает отлично, немного доработал под себя код.